# implementation if and else in protractor

Tags: selenium, if-statement, protractor

I have a scenario like this,when user select public there no problem but when selects a private,here modal should be popup and click on ok .
HTML code:

```
<div ng-show="private" class="privateSetting">
      <h5>privacy Settings</h5>
      <div>
          <md-switch ng-model="privacySwitch" style="width:35%;" class="md-primary md-switch" ng-click="privacySettings()">{{displayText}}
          </md-switch>
      </div>
      <p>privacy Msg</p>

    </div>
```

test code:

```
 element(by.css('aria-label=Private')).isDisplayed().then(function(result)
 {
     if ( result ) {
         element(by.css('[ng-click="privacySettings()"]')).click();
         browser.sleep(5000);
         element(by.className('btn btn-primary')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);

     } else {

         element(by.css('[ng-click="privacySettings()"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: getting error illegal elemnt found@Danny

Comment: can you please share the html for selecting private or public.And the modal html

Comment: I don't see an element with that attribute in the HTML you posted, but either way you need to use square brackets in your locator to access an attribute via CSS (such as aria-label).  You are probably missing quotes on the value of that attribute as well.  `element(by.css('[aria-label="Private"]'))...`

Comment: I done that too @Gunderson

Comment: `by.className()` will not accept compound class names.try using `by.css` like below `element(by.css('.btn.btn-primary'))`

Comment: getting error at line 1:Task: WebDriver.findElements(By(css selector, aria-label=Private)) An invalid or illegal specified @SudharsanSelvaraj  added HTML code above if  displayText is public no problem,when it is private, if user  click  on switch one modal should popup and click on ok.in this case it is failure.can u suggest me how to do this.

Comment: That's because the cssSelector you are using is invalid. try the selector mentioned by Gunderson.

Comment: got resolved @SudharsanSelvaraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element(by.model("privacySwitch")).isDisplayed().then(function(Private)
 {
     if ( Private ) {
        element(by.css('[ng-click="privacySettings()"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
        element(by.css('[ng-click="ok()"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);

     } else {

        element(by.css('[ng-click="privacySettings()"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
     }

 });
```